# Can't sort Google Sheet by column which value is a result of Google Apps script function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I created Google Sheet where the value of one column is a formula
`=getRank(ROW())` where `getRank()` is a function defined in Google Apps Script as (the logic of the function is not important, it returns some integer that represent rank of the row that depends on the data in the row):

```
function getRank(iRow) {
   ...
   return <some rank>;
}
```

When I try to sort the sheet by this column - I see some random results and the column's itself order doesn't change. How can it be? If I do the same logic by a formula entered in this column instead of a formula with a function call - sorting works as usual.

Comment: If getRank returns something correlated to the row number that it is on then that's a problem because sorting will change it's row number.

Comment: Custom functions are a lot slower than built-in functions.

Comment: Could you please add a sample data or spreadsheet?